# DCC Can't make up it's mind about the number of parameters a function needs

Tags: delphi, parameters, delphi-2010

I have a function declared in a unit with this prototype:

```
function MapFunction(process: THANDLE; func: Pointer; size: Cardinal) : Pointer;
```

and I am calling it with this:

```
stub := MapFunction(proc, remoteStub, 80);
```

When I compile I get this error which halts compilation:

> [DCC Error] test.pas(22): E2035 Not enough actual parameters

I fiddled with it for a while and just decided to add more parameters to see what it was thinking. So I called it with this:

```
stub := MapFunction(proc, remoteStub, 80, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1);
```

And then DCC informs me that:

> [DCC Error] test.pas(22): E2035 Not enough actual parameters
>
> [DCC Error] test.pas(22): E2034 Too many actual parameters

And commenting out that line allows the unit to compile successfully.

I just have one question: What?

I should also mention that `remoteStub` is a member variable and this function call is inside a member of that class. And that this particular method is a template method.

Comment: What is proc in this case? You could get a message of this kind if proc is a method requiring parameters.

Comment: @johnny: That'd be my guess too - `proc` sounds suspicious. :-)

Comment: Show us what `proc` and `remoteStub` are.

Comment: If **remoteStub** is a function, and you need to give it as parameter (not result), you should get the pointer on its entry point - **@remoteStub**

Answer (score 8):

You report that the line:

```
stub := MapFunction(proc, remoteStub, 80, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1);
```

results in two errors:

```
[DCC Error] test.pas(22): E2035 Not enough actual parameters
[DCC Error] test.pas(22): E2034 Too many actual parameters
```

The only explanation that makes sense is that:

- `remoteStub` is a function or procedure which expects parameters – the first error.
- all the extra 1 parameters result in the second error.

The following code behaves exactly as you report in your question and in comments to RRUZ's deleted answer:

```
function MapFunction(process: THANDLE; func: Pointer; size: Cardinal) : Pointer;
begin
  Result := nil;
end;

var
  remoteStub: procedure(x: Integer);

procedure remoteStub2(x: Integer);
begin
end;

procedure Test;
begin
  remoteStub := remoteStub2;

  //E2035 Not enough actual parameters
  MapFunction(0, remoteStub, 0);
  MapFunction(0, remoteStub2, 0);

  //Compiles and passes the entry point of the procedure
  MapFunction(0, @remoteStub, 0);
  MapFunction(0, @remoteStub2, 0);
end;
```

I can't think what else could explain what you report!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you don't have other functions with the same name and a different signature.

The code below gives you a `E2035 Not enough actual parameters`

```
program Project41;
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
uses SysUtils;

// GetFileVersion also exists in SysUtils
function GetFileVersion(const AFileName: string;extraparam:Integer): Cardinal;
begin
  beep;
end;

begin
  GetFileVersion(ParamStr(0));
end.
```

Comment: I thought of that too, but it could not explain seeing both E2035 and E2034 reported at the same source line.